# What alternatives there is for openCascade that is free and smaller

Tags: c++, 3d

Hello all
Basically I like to experiment with building 3d modeling application that could 
Also raytrace the end result , I found only the openCascade lib for such job 
My question is does it the only alternative for such task ? (im looking for library and not to deal with low level openGL)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Opencascade for a while, and i am quite impressed with its modelling capabilities. It's performance is okay for objects of simple to medium complexities, but some operations (especially 3d-booleans for objects of medium complexity) take a long time.

Also, several people have reported issues with the memory manager. Worst of all, some of the operations are neither thread safe nor reentrant in the current version.

[VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) might be an OSS alternative

**Edit 1:**

[Blender and VTK](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/Vis/VTKBlender/index.html) can be used together, as a little googling showed

Comment: thanks for the reply , what about ray tracing which engine to use ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to find an alternative but the only one I've found so far that seems workable is [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/).

Answer (score -1):

U could have a look at **salome-paltform** at http://www.salome-platform.org/

but it's huge too,i think